# All posts returned when author of 0 is queried

Tags: wp-query, author

I have a small problem when attempting to query some posts by author.
I have events and registrations. Currently I have 4 registrations, all created by User2 with the wp-admin showing that correctly. If I run the following code with a user logged on it works. User2 shows all and User1 shows none.
However, if no-one is logged on it returns all of the registrations. The user_id is being shown as 0 so it shouldn't find any of the registrations but it finds all of them, those for user 1 and those for user 2. Is there anyway I could stop this without having to check is_user_logged_in() each time.

Thanks

```
$reg_count=0;
    //if (is_user_logged_in()){
        echo "looking for registrations with author id of " . get_current_user_id();
        $registrations = new WP_Query(Array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => "registration",
            'author' => get_current_user_id(),
            'meta_key' => 'first_name',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'=> 'event_id',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                'value' => '"' . get_the_id() . '"'
            )
            )
        ));
        
        $reg_count = $registrations->found_posts;
        echo "found " . $reg_count . "  registrations wih author id of " . get_current_user_id();
    //}

?>
```

Comment: unfortunately checking the login is only option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE.  The condition you want to prevent is a ID of 0 so only run the query if it does not.

Also, DRY - don't repeat yourself.  Rather than call `get_current_user_id()` multiple times, call it once and store it.

```
$reg_count=  0;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( 0 !== $user_id ) {

    echo "looking for registrations with author id of $user_id";  //PHP will output var value in double quotes

    $registrations = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => "registration",
        'author' => $user_id,
        'meta_key' => 'first_name',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
               'key' => 'event_id',
               'compare' => 'LIKE',
               'value' => '"' . get_the_id() . '"' //Why not just get_the_id()?
            ),
         ),
     ));
    
    echo "found $registrations->found_posts registrations with author id of $user_id";
}
```

NOTE: Not at my desk - the code above is untested.  Comment here if there is a problem.

EDIT: added missing closing bracket for `IF` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Didn't know about PHP outputting var values within double quotes. I did indeed get this working but was trying not to have too many ifs. So I was just searching for the current logged on user, which would be 0 if not logged on. Would you suggest checking for userID !== 0 or use function is_user_logged_on()?

Comment: Querying with a 0 value is the problem as I see it.

Answer (score 2):

An `author` value of `0` results in the query skipping that parameter. See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329805/how-to-get-posts-without-author) and specifically [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329805/how-to-get-posts-without-author/329811#329811).

Checking if the user is logged in would still be your best bet, since that would prevent unnecessary database queries from running.